# Riled Up Riley Riddle 2

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Sorry for the last riddle

But this time I'll try not to fiddle

The important lines will begin now

This time it'll be better I vow

The prefix is where mad white workers work

With strange liquids that will make you berserk

The suffix sounds like how you walk through a wall

Drop one of 4 letters and you will have appall

The infix is best known as letter 4 times 2

Cause of a male stereotype I wish I never knew

How am I talking though? Don't bark up a storm as to why...

All you need to worry about is... what am I?

Comment: I hope I did better with this one

Comment: When have you ever posted a terrible riley riddle? :)

Comment: That first one, I forgot to give a slight hint at the end, many of these type of riddles do that

Comment: Adding to what @Duck wrote above, is the prefix Rot13(yno)?

Comment: @user477343 That's what I thought

Comment: rot13 Vf gur vasvk ngr -updated

Comment: @Duck I was also thinking that the suffix is Rot13(fuhg) because (ROT13) gb jnyx guebhtu n jnyy, lbh arrq gb bcra n qbbe, naq gura "fuhg" vg. Vs lbh qebc bar bs gur 4 yrggref (anzryl f) va gur jbeyq "nccnyyf", lbh trg "nccnyy". Ohg n jbeq fgnegvat jvgu YNO naq raqvat jvgu FUHG... V pna'g guvax bs fhpu n jbeq.

Comment: @Duck well, like you said, (ROT13) sbhe gvzrf gjb rdhnyf rvtug, naq gur jbeq sbez bs gung vf NGR. Fb vg znxrf frafr gung gur vasvk vf "ngr", ohg jung pbhyq gur znyr fgrerbglcr or? Uzz...

Comment: Could the infix be Rot13(QBO) because (ROT13) yrggre sbhe rdhnyf Q; "gvzrf" zrnaf "bs"; naq yrggre gjb rdhnyf O. Guvf znxrf QBO juvpu fgnaqf sbe Qngr bs Ovegu... orpnhfr bs fbzr znyr fgrerbglcr?

Comment: Infix: rot13: znlor vgf abg oenq ohg oen, yvxr oeb, naq gjb pncvgny Qf fgnaq sbe oenf (pybguvat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to say

> labrador

because

> The first clue -> 'lab'.

and

> you walk through walls using doors. 'dor' sounds like 'door' and is 'door' with a letter dropped.

and

> not too sure about the infix--maybe the male name 'brad' is stereotyped with aggressiveness? (no offense to any brads out there), and letter 4 x 2 or d2 is associated with dopamine which is associated with aggressiveness.

but most of all

> dogs can bark up a storm!

Comment: Was the last part too obvious? For the infix, think about 2 Ds

Comment: The part about barking? I mostly came up with the word using the prefix and suffix hint, and then saw it was supported by the barking clue.

Comment: Not sure about the infix--maybe Philipp is onto something in the comments under the question?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't read the cryptography that you guys do, you'll have to translate it. Sorry

Comment: @XavierStanton to decrypt the messages, copy and paste the ciphertext into [this website, rot13.com](https://rot13.com/). Hope this helps!