# Riled Up Riley Riddle 3

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge, language

This riddle is intended to be spectacular

Because you need more than one vernacular

My prefix can fly and it can also steal

Use French, and you will seal the deal

Spanish in the suffix is something you'll hear

Every January when you start a new year

The infix is draped in a familiar tin

The essentials came after a long time sin

These clues are burning hot and sly

Because of this, you should know... what am I?

Comment: Still trying to figure out the answer but I really like the way your riddle rhymes :)

Comment: As soon as I read the first two lines, I thought: *"It's more than spectacular to use the vernacular, it's wizard, it's smashing, it's keen.... Oh Chitty Chitty Bang Bang"*

Comment: That was a pure coincidence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> volcano?

First,

> according to Google translate, vol can mean flight or theft in French...

Second,

> cans can be coated in tin

Third,

> año means year in Spanish

Also

> the clues are 'burning'

Comment: You correctly answered the [OP's previous Riley Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69818/riled-up-riley-riddle-2/69820) and now you just do it again!

Comment: haha I got kind of lucky this time; I already knew the Spanish part and that cans can be coated in tin.

Comment: @XavierStanton any hint on what the third to last line points to? I feel like I might have the correct word, but I can't seem to figure out what that line alludes to.

Comment: Good job, the third last line refers to the tin/can opener, which wasn't invented until years after tinned/canned food

Comment: @1848, if you're interested, maybe [this reference guide](https://www.alt-codes.net/) might help you!